# Javascript & HTML on page calculations

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am fairly new to HTML & Javascript and I have been assigned a task to create a HTML form for a restaurant which allows the user to input their information for a booking.

So far I have created the form for the website and validated each input field in order to ensure the correct information is entered into the necessary fields.

I have also tried to enable the total cost to be calculated on screen so the user can see how much their booking will cost before they click the submit button. However, the code I have thus far does not seem to be functioning as the total price never increases from 0 if an option is picked.

Here is the relevant html code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Select Party Size:</strong>
<br>
<select name="party" id="party" onblur="validateSelect(name)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="5">1 Person (£5)</option>
<option value="10">2 People (£10)</option>
<option value="15">3 People (£15)</option>
<option value="20">4 People (£20)</option>
<option value="25">5 People (£25)</option>
<option value="30">6 People (£30)</option>
<option value="35">7 People (£35)</option>
<option value="40">8 People (£40)</option>
<option value="45">9 People (£45)</option>
<option value="50">10+ People (£50)</option>
</select>

...

<strong> VIP Area? </strong>
<br>
Yes (+£5) <input name="hand" id="left" value="5" onblur="validateRadio(id)" type="radio">
No <input name="hand" id="right" value="0" onblur="validateRadio(id)" checked="" type="radio">
<span class="validateError" id="handError" style="display: none;">Please specify whether you would like a table in the VIP area.</span>

<strong> Total booking cost based on party size <span id="price">0</span> VIP selection: </strong>
```

Here is the relevant javascript to perform the calculations:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('change', '#party', function(e) {
        $('#price').html(parseInt($(this).val()) + parseInt($('input[name="hand"]:checked').val()));
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="hand"]', function(e) {
        $('#price').html(parseInt($('#party').val()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

For example, if the customer selects that there are 6 people in their party(+£30) and they also wish to be seated in the VIP area(+£5), the total price displayed at the bottom of the page would be £35. If anyone has any suggestions as to why my code isn't functioning I would appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Comment: I may be missing something but it seems to be working for me http://jsfiddle.net/mgymqzn0/

Comment: go to the console and check if any error is thrown

Comment: it is giving error **Uncaught ReferenceError: validateSelect is not defined** if i debug it , it is going on this line**<select name="party" id="party" onblur="validateSelect(name)">** now you found the culprit, fix it.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa thanks for your reply, I'm not sure why the 0 figure does not update for me, as I am relatively new to javascript could you point me in the right direction to fixing this?

Comment: @05K3 The `validateSelect` function doesn't exist, either create it or remove the onblur event.

Comment: Is it possible another line of code in my js / html file could be affecting the 0 from increasing?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I removed the onblur event but still the 0 does not increase :(

Comment: check this fiddle, is it working for you??
http://jsfiddle.net/c9oy4vmg/2/

Comment: @05K3 In that case I would suggest creating a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which demonstrates the issue you are having. The one I put together had no issues.

Comment: @05K3 Are you certain that the jQuery library is being loaded when you run your test?

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Yes the Jquery works perfectly for me but not when I implement it :(

Comment: you need to remove all the onblur events when you are implementing.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes http://jsfiddle.net/sda64sw2/ Ive added the whole of my site to jfiddle & it seems to be working on there fine, how bizzare? Not sure why it wont seem to work when I open the website on my local computer

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa still no change friend :(

Comment: can you provide the link??

Comment: @05K3 You running the site from your local hard disk? Are you absolutely sure that the jQuery library is being loaded? Have you tried this in multiple browsers?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Yes from a local computer, I have also tried running off my uni server but still no luck. How can I check if the jQuery library is functional? Would there be a way to perform the calculations without the use of jQuery?

Comment: @05K3 If you are using IE you'll probably get a message along the lines of _"IE restricted this webpage from running scripts or active x controls"_.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Sorry I forgot to mention, I have tried running the page in safari, firefox & chrome but still no luck

Comment: @05K3 In that case open Chrome, press F12, go to the _Console_ tab and load the page. Let me know what messages you see.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes wow not sure what happened but I moved the script tag on my html document and it suddenly decided to work! Thanks a lot for your feedback friend :)